# Jquery ajax select drop down works in FF and chrome but not IE 7-9

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I know this has been asked so many times by now you all are probably sick of it.  I'm just stuck and have already spent about 4 hours on this.  I've read through many suggestions already about the

```
    cache:false,
```

option and adding certain "content-types", but when I do this, it no longer works in any browser.

I followed the tutorial as found here: http://www.x-developer.com/php-scripts/loading-drop-downs-with-ajax-php-and-fetching-values-from-database-without-refreshing-the-page

and I modified it of course to my needs, mostly just the mysql and identifiers.

This is what I have in my head section:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function get_cities(country)
    {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/cities.php", 
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
    $("#state").html("<option>Loading ...</option>");
    },
    data: "country="+country,
    success: function(msg){
    $("#state").html(msg);

    }
    });
    } 
    </script>
```

In IE, it gets to the Loading.... part, and does nothing, it doesn't populate the option field as it does in Chrome and FF.

Do you see anything in the tutorial that he may have left out that is crucial for the operation in IE?

Thanks,

Comment: Press F12 to bring up the Developer Tools, go to "Scripts" tag and hit "enable debugging". See what messages you get. Add them to the question if still stuck. Alos ALWAYS trap errors from AJAX calls - servers may fail for any reason and you need to handle it. So add "error" function to your call - this may also give you a clue as to what's going on

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the data object as a key value pair..

Instead of

```
data: "country="+country,
```

try

```
data: { "country" : country },
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and still no go.  It still works in the other browsers, just no luck in IE yet.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your `$("#state")` is already a dropdown list.

in `cities.php`, you'll need to remove the `<select>` tag.

```
<?php
// Code for cities.php
$country_id = $_REQUEST['country_id'];

$sql_city = "SELECT * FROM CITY WHERE country_id = '".$country_id."'";
$result_city = mysql_query($sql_city);

// REMOVE THIS LINE
//echo "<select name='city'>";

while($row_city = mysql_fetch_array($result_city))
{
echo "<option value='".$row_city['id']."'>".$row_city['city']."</option>";
}

// AND REMOVE THIS LINE  
// echo "</select>";

?>
```